# Ubuntu & Win 10 dual boot: after installing Ubuntu 17.04, USB ports stop working in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, usb

The title states the problem: after I installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Win 10 (same drive, different partition), my USB ports turn off after I select Windows in GRUB.

The system does not freeze: notifications still appear, the system clock updates, it's just that none of my USB devices seem to be enabled. This is problematic as this includes the keyboard and mouse, so I cannot troubleshoot from within Windows. USB support is enabled in BIOS/EFI. I have tried switching the USB ports and devices around, and it looks like all of them are 'dead'.

My fear is that the dual boot messes with the ports somehow but I have not found more precise descriptions or even solutions of the problem. Is this a known issue and could there be a solution to it?

Comment: In your BIOS, what are the USB settings? They should probably be legacy. Also, check the manufacturer's web site for a BIOS update. Report back.

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed an update for my BIOS (MSI H97-G43M board), but applying it did not remedy the issue. Legacy USB support is enabled. 

What I notice though is that USB ports only get disabled if I make a cold boot into Windows. If I boot into Ubuntu, then reboot and start up Windows, the USB ports function. Odd! There must be something about the USB ports that's under the control of Ubuntu/GRUB but not Windows anymore, but what could that be?

Comment: How many USB devices do you have? What are they? Disconnect all but one, and try it and see if USB works with just the one. **If that works**, add another, etc. Trying to eliminate a USB device issue. If that **does not** work, that device may be suspect, remove it, put it aside, and try with another singular USB device. Get the idea? Report back.

Comment: Hi there, I have plenty of USB devices - keyboard mouse, rudder, joystick, an Oculus headset with 2 cameras, and the occasional Arduino and USB stick. I removed all devices and saw if I could get Windows to register any of them on different usb ports (powered hub, front, back), but Windows didn't register any of them (well, unless I boot the system in Ubuntu first).

Comment: Did you remember to unplug the powered hub when testing?